# Grails set default value of scaffolded dropdown box

Tags: grails

Is it possible to set the default value for a generated (scaffolded) State dropdown box in Grails?  I am hoping that this is something I can do within either the domain class or the controller class:

```
class State {

    String name
    String code

    static mapping = { sort name: "asc" }

    String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Person implements Comparable {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    State state

    String toString() {
        return this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName;
    }
}
```

I have tried explicitly setting `String name="Pennsylvania"` and `String code="PA"` in the State domain class with no luck. I am bootstrapping the State data in Bootstrap.groovy:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    if (!State.count()) {
        new State(name: "Alabama", code:"AL").save(failOnError: true)
        new State(name: "Alaska", code:"AK").save(failOnError: true)
        new State(name: "Arizona", code:"AZ").save(failOnError: true)
        new State(name: "Arkansas", code:"AR").save(failOnError: true)
        ....
    }
}
```

---

Updated:

PersonController.groovy:

```
def create() {
    // [personInstance = new Person(params)]
    def personInstance = new Person(params)
    personInstance.state = new State("Pennsylvania", "PA")
    [personInstance: personInstance]
}
```

State.groovy:

```
public State(String name, String code) {
    this.name = name
    this.code = code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to set the default value of the state dropdown for the "new Person" page, then you would probably want to make the default value of Person's 'state' member be the 'Pennsylvania' state that you create in Bootstrap.

Actually, I think that a better way to do this would be to actually generate the PersonController, and then modify the 'create' closure to set the initial value of Person.state

Comment: Thanks. I am looking to try this out but, for some reason, I receive the following error in my application after generating the controller (before making any code changes): "message /myapp/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/person/list.jsp, description The requested resource is not available." I tried cleaning the project multiple times with no luck.

Comment: once you generate the controller, you need the matching jsps too. You can either generate them too (with 'grails generate-views'), or write them yourself.

Comment: That is good to know, thanks. That fixed it. As for setting the default value, can you please take a look at my updated code above? I'm unfortunately a Grails novice, and I am still trying to learn. The code above does not change the default value. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but in the controller, instead of assigning a new State to the personInstance, you should use the one that you created in the Bootstrap. e.g. personInstance.state = State.findByCode('PA')